# Open rate by domain over time - SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, group-by, sqlserver

I'm trying to figure out open rate over time based on domain however, it seems to error or timeout every time I run it. I've limited it to just gmail, yahoo, and AOL for now.

```
SELECT 
  o.domain
  , s.eventdate
  , count(o.subscriberkey) AS Open
  , count(s.subscriberkey) AS Sent 
FROM _Sent s 
LEFT JOIN _Open o ON s.jobid = o.jobid 
WHERE o.domain like '%gmail.com%' 
  OR o.domain like '%yahoo.com%' 
  OR o.domain like '%aol.com%'
Group By o.domain, s.eventdate
```

**I would like the output to look something like this:**

```
| Domain | EventDate | Opens | Sent   |
+--------+-----------+-------+--------+
| gmail  | 6/1/2016  | 5,000 | 20,000 |
| yahoo  | 6/1/2016  | 1,000 | 15,000 |
| aol    | 6/1/2016  | 500   | 10,000 |
| gmail  | 5/29/2016 | 6,100 | 35,000 |
| yahoo  | 5/29/2016 | 1,200 | 20,000 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you're grouping by raw event date, so every single timestamp is a group?

Try convert(varchar, s.eventdate, 101) in your select. That should change the date to 'mm/dd/yyyy' format and group by the whole day.

Maybe also try putting in a date range in case the query is just timing out because the dataset is so big. (e.g. 'where s.eventdate between '2016-05-01' and '2016-06-01')

Comment: It took a way shorter time to run but unfortunately, it still errored. I also limited s.eventdate >= '3/1/2016'

Comment: any other thoughts?